# How the Android Compose View notifies the ViewModel about happened navigation - trying to understand code example?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to do Android Compose navigation initiated by the ViewModel. This example description https://medium.com/@ffvanderlaan/navigation-in-jetpack-compose-using-viewmodel-state-3b2517c24dde and project https://github.com/Frank1234/ViewModelNavigationCompose suggest to do navigation from the View but based on the state that is kept in the ViewModel.

The description https://medium.com/@ffvanderlaan/navigation-in-jetpack-compose-using-viewmodel-state-3b2517c24dde contains activity diagram, that includes step 4 and step 5 in whose the View notifies the ViewModel that navigation has happened.

My question is - how this step 4 (notificiation by View) is implemented in the example code https://github.com/Frank1234/ViewModelNavigationCompose? I can not find this implementation. I.e. there is view https://github.com/Frank1234/ViewModelNavigationCompose/blob/master/app/src/main/java/nl/frank/vmnc/ui/content/ContentPage.kt but I don't see any code in this View that could catch the navigation event and that could notify the ViewModel about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the ContentPage code there are onClick methods defined as:

```
...
onClick = viewModel::onNextWithDelayClicked
...
```

What this means is that ContentPage receives a reference to viewModel and then calls the `onNextWithDelayClicked()` method inside the viewModel

I think you're confused by the shorthand notation used in onClick, it is equivalent to:

```
...
onClick = { viewModel.onNextWithDelayClicked() }
...
```